# Can't connect remotely to Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.5

Running Postgresql 9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.

My /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
#remote connection 
host    all             all            0.0.0.0/0              trust
```

My /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
#ssl = true             # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
                    # (change requires restart)
```

My netstat -nlp | grep 5432:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22621/postgres  
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      22621/postgres  
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10261951 22621/postgres      /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I'm able to connect locally, but can't connect remotely. When I try to connect from another computer, the command times out.

Comment: Are you sure there is no appliance, etc. blocking TCP 5432? What happens when you telnet to TCP 5432 from the remote machine?

Comment: telnet <myprivateIPaddress> 5432 -->
Trying XXX.XXX.XX.XXX........ 
connection times out

Comment: I also disabled my firewall as @Z4-tier suggested

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have a firewall running on the same host as your database that is blocking 5432. I'm not an Ubuntu wizard, but I think you can do

```
ufw disable
```

to turn it off. If that doesn't work, try

```
service iptables stop
```

or possibly

```
iptables -F
```

Note that these will (of course) turn off your firewall, so be aware of that. The last one will flush your firewall rules so you will need to re-read your ruleset if you want to turn it back on.

and as @Pancake suggested, see what happens if you simply telnet to 5432 from another host (or use netcat, etc...).

Comment: Sorry, this is the only place I'm allowed to comment, apparently....

Is the machine you are using to test the connection on the same subnet as the database server? Are you on a corporate/business/something network that might be dropping those packets between the test server and the database?

Comment: Also, since you didn't mention it in the question:  did you make sure to have postgres re-read those config files after modifying them (assuming you made changes) ?

Comment: It's not on the same subnet -- could that be the issue? This setup used to work when the server and client were connected on the same subnet. 

I restarted postgres (sudo systemctl restart postgresql), which has it reread the config files.

Comment: That's giving me the feeling that a network device is dropping the packets somewhere between the 2 hosts. It might be worth a shot is try spinning up the database on a different port and see if it suddenly starts working. Maybe try a port that you know is open, like port 22 (but you'd have to reconfigure sshd in that case) or be a bit more methodical and check for open ports using nmap/netcat. This might draw the ire of your net admins. and it might not work, depending on how they are inspecting and filtering traffic. Might be easier to just ask  if they are dropping your traffic :)